# Github actions not working after npm start

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, next.js, cypress, github-actions

I have a very simple config in order to run e2e tests with Cypress using Github Actions in a Nextjs app. When it reaches the `npm start` command, although it seems to work since it gives the correct output: `> Ready on http://localhost:3000`, the step stays in pending state without ever advancing to the next step.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Following github actions config (`.github/workflows/nodejs.yml`):

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm ci
        npm run build --if-present
        npm start
        npx wait-on http://localhost:3000
      env:
        CI: true
    - name: Run Cypress
      run: |
        npx cypress run
      env:
        CI: true
```

Comment: I wonder if the problem is `npx wait-on http://localhost:3000`. Have you tried `npx wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000`? I think I experienced something before where `localhost` didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the control operator `&` works for me. Try the following.

```
    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm ci
        npm run build --if-present
        npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000
      env:
        CI: true
```

From [man bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/bash.1.html)

> If  a  command  is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in
>          the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and  the
>          return  status  is 0.  These are referred to as asynchronous commands.  Commands separated
>          by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate  in  turn.
>          The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.

Comment: Is this still working in 2022? The server seem to be down on the next step.

Comment: For GitHub Actions I had to change `http://localhost:3000` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.