# How github-actions run test on (production) build results instead of develop mode

Tags: node.js, github, yarnpkg, package.json, github-actions

I currently have a github action like this in a Create React App

```yaml
name: Percy
on: [push]
jobs:
  percy:
    name: Visual Testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        env:
          PERCY_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERCY_TOKEN }}
        with:
          start: yarn start
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'
          command-prefix: 'percy exec -- npx'
```

But I would like to `yarn build` (instead of `yarn start`) and `serve` these results for my tests (**cypress**, etc) - so I see how the tests goes on something that has gone through `webpack`.

I have tried a lot of different things (like `start: yarn build && yarn serve -s build -p 3000`) but have come to the conclusion that I need some guidance.

```sh
...
$ react-scripts build '&&' yarn serve -s build -p 3000
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  49.3 KB  build/static/js/2.98954ae7.chunk.js
  3.01 KB  build/static/js/main.9bc31c1d.chunk.js
  1.13 KB  build/static/css/main.9e43f7ef.chunk.css
  818 B    build/static/css/2.a2fbc952.chunk.css
  779 B    build/static/js/runtime-main.fe4fcbcb.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy

Done in 10.36s.
http://localhost:3000 timed out on retry 61 of 2
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: If you want to host a development version app on Github, then it's not how it works. Github Actions can run automated tests, make builds and upload them somewhere, but not host a running application. P.S. You can however make a build and deploy it on github pages, or you can use something like netlify.

Comment: I don't want to deploy the app - just want the test to be as close to the production as possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying. With github actions you can only run automation tests, e.g., but it will not give you a public URL where you can access it on port 3000.

Comment: I apologise if I'm uncleared. I wish to test the results of what get processed by webpack and not I get from yarn start.

Comment: Oh, that clears things a bit. If you are looking to inspect the actual generated code probably you want to upload artifacts - see https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts. Does it help?

Comment: Also take a look at the env vars - I don't see that you define it anywhere - something like `NODE_ENV=production`, but that's really up to your build config

Comment: thanks for the links @AlexBuznik - My problems more to have it serving the compiled code so my tests can access it.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424797/753451

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexBuznik - the answer from Arun Kumar Mohan works perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`build`](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#build-app) parameter to build the app using `yarn build` and the [`start`](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#start-server) parameter to start the server using `npx serve`.

```yaml
- name: Cypress run
  uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
  env:
    PERCY_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERCY_TOKEN }}
  with:
    build: yarn build
    start: npx serve -s build -l 3000
    wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'
    command-prefix: 'percy exec -- npx'
```